# How to return related translation of a field in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have trasnlated fields in database model like below

```
class Property(models.Model):
    title_en = models.CharField
    title_fa = models.CharField
    title_ar = models.CharField
```

Right now instead of returning all the above fields in response, I use `SerializerMethodField` for returning related translation based on user language like below.

And for updating or creating I must include those field names with their postfix.

```
class PropertySerialzier(serializer.ModelSerialzier):
    title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = (
              'title',
              'title_en',
              'title_fa',
              'title_ar',
        )

    @staticmethod
    def get_title(instance: Property):
        return getattr(instance, f'title_{get_language()}')
```

How can I write something general that I can use for other models and serializers? Because the project will be going to have a lot of translated fields.

And also how to include these fields in the `fields` variable for updating or creating instances without returning in response?

Maybe something like overriding methods in `ModelSerialzier` class in the Django-rest library?